# How to find median within 3-day time interval using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

My data is in long format with id, day, and recorded measurement. I would like a new variable, which generates the median value within each 3 day interval (not rolling but day 1-3, 4-6, 7-9, etc).

I got as far as this using dplyr for the overall median but not sure how to code for every 3 day interval by id:

```
test%>%group_by(id)%>%mutate(m=median(o2))
```

Here is some data:

```
structure(list(id = c("1A", "1A", "1A", "1A", "1A", "1A", "1A", 
"1A", "1A", "1A"), day = 1:10, o2 = c(40L, 70L, 100L, 100L, 30L, 
35L, 30L, 30L, 40L, 40L)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(cols = list(id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), day = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), o2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), class = "col_spec"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by id and 3-day interval, and then calculate the median.

```
library(dplyr)

test %>%
  group_by(id, interval_id = (day-1) %/% 3) %>%
  mutate(m = median(o2))

#  id      day    o2 interval_id     m
#  <chr> <int> <int>       <dbl> <int>
# 1A        1    40           0    70
# 1A        2    70           0    70
# 1A        3   100           0    70
# 1A        4   100           1    35
# 1A        5    30           1    35
# 1A        6    35           1    35
# 1A        7    30           2    30
# 1A        8    30           2    30
# 1A        9    40           2    30
# 1A       10    40           3    40
```

Comment: Thank you Aron - this worked perfectly and addressed my comments below about the interval group id not ceasing at the final day within id . Interval_id renews for each new id in your solution, thereby, the median calculation to is strictly restricted within id.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `gl` to create groups of 3 days and calculate `median` in each group.

```
library(dplyr)

test %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(group = gl(n()/3, 3), 
         group = cumsum(group != lag(group, default = first(group)))) %>%
  group_by(id, group) %>%
  summarise(med = median(o2))



#  id    group   med
#  <chr> <int> <int>
#1 1A        0    70
#2 1A        1    35
#3 1A        2    30
#4 1A        3    40
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I should have clarified I wanted the median for a fixed 3 day epoch rather than rolling. So, med_col=70 for the first 3 rows (day1-3), 35 for each row day 4-6. Can your code be amended for this?

Comment: This will take the last element (remainder 3 -3 -3 -1) and assign it a `group` of 1, so in summary it is summarised with group 1. I think it should be something like `dd %>% group_by(id, grp = gl(n()/3, 3), grp2 = data.table::rleid(grp)) %>% summarise(med = median(o2))`

Comment: Thank you @Ronak Shah! This is very close to what I want, however, for day 10, group=1 again rather than 4. If the last group <3 days, is it possible to record the value if the final group is one day long or median if there are are 2 remaining days?

Comment: @Sotos this amendment answered my last comment. Many thanks!!

Comment: No problem... :)

Comment: You can further simplify it by `df %>%
 group_by(id, day = gl(ceiling(n() / 3), 3, length = n()))`.

Comment: Thank you all for these solutions. When I ran all of these on my data, I noticed that the newly created group, group2,and day do not restart at 1 for the next id but continue to increase in number regardless of the previous id's final day. I am not sure why given that we have group_by id. Any ideas?

Comment: Does my answer below (with data table) do the same?

Comment: @Sotos - I checked your DT solution, and the rleid group does not restart with the next id but continues from the previous value.

Comment: Ohh..ok, I see what you need

Comment: @SK77 I see. I had to create groups within each `ID`. Updated the answer, hopefully this covers it.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a good use for `data.table::rleid`, here is the `data.table` answer,

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dd)[, grp := gl(.N, 3, length = .N), by = id][, .(med = median(o2)), .(id, rleid(grp))]

#   id rleid med
#1: 1A     1  70
#2: 1A     2  35
#3: 1A     3  30
#4: 1A     4  40
```